# Android Facebook API - I receive emails only for some fb accounts

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have been using the Facebook SDK for Android a bit now. I have been having trouble where one of my testers could not create an account in my app using Facebook. After some debugging I figured out that for some reason when he tries to login / register the JSON object that contains the information does not come with his **email**. This only happens for HIS account!

Does anyone know why this could happen?

*(I have included a simplified version of my login code so you can see if there is anything wrong with it that might cause it)*

```
List<String> permissionNeeds = Arrays.asList("public_profile", "user_friends", "email");
loginButton.setReadPermissions(permissionNeeds);

loginButton.registerCallback(mCallbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(final LoginResult loginResult) {
        GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(
                loginResult.getAccessToken(), new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted(JSONObject object, GraphResponse response) {
                        try {
                            Log.d(TAG, object.toString()); // Has no email sometimes!
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                            Log.e(TAG, String.format("Error with facebook login: %s", e.getMessage()));
                        }
                    }
                });
        Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
        parameters.putString("fields", "id,name,picture,email,gender");
        request.setParameters(parameters);
        request.executeAsync();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancel() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(FacebookException error) {
        Log.d(TAG, String.format("Error with facebook login: %s", error.getMessage()));
    }
});

loginButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithReadPermissions(SplashActivity.this,
                Arrays.asList("public_profile", "user_friends", "email"));
    }
});
```

If any more information is needed, please tell me I'll be happy to add some.

Thanks!

Comment: Does the account _have_ an email address on file with Facebook? (That is not necessarily the case, f.e. if someone registered using their mobile.) Also, that email address must be verified, otherwise it will not be returned. // Your app should not _rely_ on getting an email address for every user. If you _need_ an email address, then implement a step where the user can enter it manually.

Answer (score 0):

So turns out that my tester had an inactive email account.

In general you should never be counting on every Facebook user having an email address.